# Wordpress WP admin - cannot modify header information after wordpress update

Tags: wordpress

After I updated wordpress I'm getting this error.

Wp admin URL
http://bit.ly/1TbLXVa

I think something wrong with the /theme/mytheme/functions.php becouse when I disable it it works, but if I disable the site doesn't work. Not sure what the issue is. I even put an old functions.php from the back up.

Attached the functions.php file appriciate if anything can help me.
http://bit.ly/1TRr5lo
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you check both the start and end of the file for whitespace! And let me know if still the problem is there. For me, in the past, I had white spaces in my functions.php file.

Comment: Try to delete your cache AND cookies after an update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Note: by the look of the first line in your functions.php it looks like your site has been hacked. See http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked on how to proceed with this.

Comment: My site has been hacked?

Comment: Gerald Schneider- I searched and I couldn't find a relevant post and its not a duplicate of what you have posted there this is a Wordpress issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ash, are you using any ftp software? if yes then change your file transfer type to binary as in FTP Client,

- In Total Commander:  locate ‘Transfer mode’ tab in tool bar on top. Then using drop-down selector click ‘Binary (archives, doc etc.)'
- FileZilla: in top menu select Transfer> Transfer type> Binary
- CuteFTP: navigate to File> Transfer Type> Binary

**[Refernce Link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-set-binary-transfer-mode-in-filezilla-totalcommander-and-cuteftp.html)**

Comment: What difference it makes?

Comment: As far as I can tell is "Binary" transfer mode of FTP copies files exactly, byte for byte. When bringing text files between different operating systems, though, this might not be what you want -- different operating systems use different codes to represent line breaks. The "ASCII" mode exists for this purpose: it automatically translates all line endings from the source system's format to the destination's.  [Source](http://serverfault.com/questions/110699/ascii-vs-binary-vs-auto)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11211737)

Comment: I have explained the answer, I just signup yesterday to share & gain my knowledge with other developer. thanks for guiding me @sebastianbrosch.